# How to cancel waitpid if child has no status change?

Tags: c, waitpid

Disclaimer: Absolute newbie in C, i was mostly using Java before.

In many C beginner tutorials, `waitpid` is used in process management examples to wait for its child processes to finish (or have a status change using options like `WUNTRACED`). However, i couldn't find any information about how to continue if no such status change occurs, either by direct user input or programmatic (e.g. timeout). So what is a good way to undo `waitpid`? Something like `SIGCONT` for stopped processes, but instead for processes delayed by `waitpid`.

Alternatively if the idea makes no sense, it would be interesting to know why.

Comment: [waitpid manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid): "WNOHANG return immediately if no child has exited.". Is that what you need?

Comment: Well i was thinking more of user input or timeout so i thought not at first glance, but the solution by dbush uses WNOHANG in a timeout loop which could also be a wait for user input loop. Was hoping i wouldn't need to run a (potentially) infinite loop but just wait for an interrupt but it should work. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't make that very clear. You could handle `SIGCHLD` instead. But still not sure if that is what you really mean.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I was just looking at the tutorials and thought: Once i set a parent process to wait with waitpid, how can i undo this after the fact without ANY change to the child. So not if child does x do z, but child can do whatever, i just want to revert the waitpid on parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about if I suggest using `alarm()`? `alarm()` delivers `SIGALRM` after the countdown passes (See `alarm()` man page for more details). But from the  `signals` man page, `SIGALRM` default disposition is to terminate the process. So, you need to register a signal handler for handling the `SIGALRM`. Code follows like this...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void sigalrm(int signo)
{
    return; // Do nothing !
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction act, oldact;

    act.sa_handler = sigalrm;   // Set the signal handler
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;

#ifdef SA_INTERRUPT // If interrupt defined set it to prevent the auto restart of sys-call
    act.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
#endif

    sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, &oldact);

    pid_t fk_return = fork();
    if (fk_return == 0) {   // Child never returns
        for( ; ; );
    }

    unsigned int wait_sec = 5;
    alarm(wait_sec);    // Request for SIGALRM

    time_t start = time(NULL);
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    int tmp_errno = errno;  // save the errno state, it may be modified in between function calls.
    time_t end = time(NULL);

    alarm(0);  // Clear a pending alarm
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &oldact, NULL);

    if (tmp_errno == EINTR) {
        printf("Child Timeout, waited for %d sec\n", end - start);
        kill(fk_return, SIGINT);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (tmp_errno != 0)    // Some other fatal error
        exit(1);

    /* Proceed further */

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Child Timeout, waited for 5 sec
```

**Note:** You don't need to worry about `SIGCHLD` because its default disposition is to ignore.

#### EDIT

For the completeness, it is guaranteed that `SIGALRM` is not delivered to the child. This is from the man page of `alarm()`

> Alarms created by alarm() are preserved across execve(2) and are not inherited by children created via fork(2).

#### EDIT 2

I don't know why it didn't strike me at first. A simple approach would be to block `SIGCHLD` and call `sigtimedwait()` which supports timeout option. The code goes like this...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    sigset_t sigmask;
    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGCHLD);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigmask, NULL);

    pid_t fk_return = fork();
    if (fk_return == 0) {   // Child never returns
        for( ; ; );
    }

    if (sigtimedwait(&sigmask, NULL, &((struct timespec){5, 0})) < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) {
            printf("Timeout\n");
            kill(fk_return, SIGINT);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    waitpid(fk_return, NULL, 0);    // Child should have terminated by now.

    /* Proceed further */

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Timeout
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand process handling & signal use better, and also for the examples to provide orientation. All 3 answers were really helpful & upvoted, but since this helped me most i selected is as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to `waitpid` takes a set of flags.  You want to include the `WNOHANG` flag, which tells `waitpid` to return immediately if no child process has exited.

After adding this option, you would sit in a loop a sleep for some period of time and try again if nothing has exited.  Repeat until either a child has returned or until your timeout has passed.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way without countdown loop, e.g. user pressing ESC or sending interrupt but the solution should work for me. I'll try it out tomorrow and if works ill mark as solved and solution. Thank you,

Comment: You should handle user input and other events as you normally would: you have some event loop that receives the input and dispatches it. All that you're adding is a poll of the PIDs you're interested in. The "countdown" loop is a normal thing, known as the event loop, except it should do more than just wait. If it's "just" a non-GUI process, you can still have an event loop - it makes life easier.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand waitpid better. All 3 answers were really helpful & upvoted, but since i can only select one as the solution i marked the one by Mohith Reddy.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for process to die on a typical Unix system is an absolute PITA. The portable way would be to use various signals to interrupt `wait` function: `SIGALARM` for timeout, `SIGTERM`/`SIGINT` and others for "user input" event. This relies on a global state and thus might be impossible to do.

The non-portable way would be to use [`pidfd_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_open.2.html) with `poll`/`epoll` on Linux, [`kqueue`](https://man.openbsd.org/kqueue.2) with a `EVFILT_PROC` filter on BSDs.

Note that on Linux this allows waiting for a process to terminate, you will still have to retrieve status via [`waitid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitid) with `P_PIDFD`.

If you still want to mix in "user events", add [`signalfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) to the list of descriptors on Linux or `EVFILT_SIGNAL` filter of `kqueue` on BSDs.

Another possible solution is to spawn a "process reaper" thread which is responsible for reaping of all processes and setting some event in a process object of your choice: [`futex`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/futex) word, [`eventfd`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd) etc. Waiting on such objects can be done with a timeout. This requires everyone to agree to use the same interface for process spawning which might or might not be reasonable. Afaik Java implementations [use this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3835830/1143634).

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand process handling & signal use better. All 3 answers were really helpful & upvoted, but since i can only select one solution i marked the one by Mohith Reddy.